# .htaccess 301 redirect only work for 1 new link

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, canonical-link, canonicalization

I have .htaccess file with redirect 301 on it and placed right under the  rewriteengine

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#now this is the redirect
Redirect 301 /blog.php?slug=konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions https://jpi.or.id/blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah

Redirect 301 /blog/2021/02/11/konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions https://jpi.or.id/blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah

</IfModule>
```

only 2nd redirect works, the one with the get method are not redirected, am i doing wrong?

EDITED :

this is my entire mod rewrite :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /blog.php?slug=konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions https://jpi.or.id/blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /blog/2021/02/11/konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions https://jpi.or.id/blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah

Redirect 301 /blog.php?slug=konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions /blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah
RewriteRule ^blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah   /blog.php?slug=konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions
```

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches against the _path_ component of the URL only, you can not use it to check on query string contents. You will need to use mod_rewrite for that, a combination of RewriteCond and RewriteRule.

Comment: @CBroe how can i use mod_rewrite combination without override my other rewrite link?, can i use multiple mod_rewrite tag?

Comment: A "mod_rewrite tag" is not a thing. Multiple RewriteConds and RewriteRules can be used, of course. If you are completely new to the matter, then perhaps start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained for some basics.

Comment: Can you tell us what your other rewrite rules are?  It is hard to tell you how they might conflict without seeing them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller i edited my post to see the entire Mod rewrite that i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually not a good idea to mix `RewriteRule` and `Redirect 301` directives.  They can conflict with each other in unexpected ways. You depend of `RewriteRule` so you should implement your redirects with more of them.

`Redirect 301` can't redirect based on query strings (`?...`) in the URL, so you need to implement RewriteRules for that redirect anyway.

When you have rules for redirecting specific URLs, they should go at the top of the `.htaccess` file so that they take precedence over the other more general rules.

I would recommend disabling the directory index because I fear it would conflict with your `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]` rule.

I don't see `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess` file, despite that your snippet you posted to start with has it.

Try this as your `.htaccess`:

```
# Disable index.html, index.php default functionality
DirectoryIndex disabled

RewriteEngine On

# Permanent URL redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions$
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ https://jpi.or.id/blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/2021/02/11/konsolidasi-tanah-frequently-asked-questions$ https://jpi.or.id/blog/2021/02/11/pengertian-konsolidasi-tanah  [R=301,L]

# Forward URLs without .php extension to existing PHP file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect index.php URLs to the directory
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Use index.php as a front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen, i am sorry,  i am copy the code under the rewrite module, thanks for the help